# Does "as shown follows" sound right?

Tags: grammaticality

Is "as shown follows" the right way to say it? Here is a generic example:

> If X, then Y should be organized as shown follows:

If it actually is ok, does it sound natural or should I replace it with something else?

**Edit:** In case someone is interested, my copyeditor changed the sentence to:

> If X, then Y should be organized as shown next:

Answer (score 4):

It is not idiomatic or grammatical. Three possible ways to reword it would be "as shown below", "as shown in the following", or simply "as follows".

> If X, then Y should be organized as follows:

"Like this" is yet another possiblity, but of a somewhat lower register.

Comment: Perhaps the sentence comes from not realizing that we can use one verb or the other, but not both.

Comment: Except you can use both: "If X, then Y should be shown as follows:"

Answer (score -1):

Instead of "as shown next", why not "as shown here"? Alternately, try "as shown in the following".

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.